# i am trying to display user transactions stored in user1 file . i want to align transactions according to its type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The compiler shows error that expected token before if.how to solve this......................................................................................................................................................................

```
import transactions from './user1.js'
import {Row,Col} from 'react-bootstrap'
const history = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Row>
               {transactions.map(tr=>(
              if (tr.type=="Rsend")) {
                  <h3>a</h3>
              } else {
                  <h3>b</h3>
              }
             <h3>aaa</h3>
             
               ))}
               
            </Row>
        </div>
  }  


export default history
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't even pass the syntax check. I assume this is what you are looking for.

```
import transactions from './user1.js'
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Fragment } from 'react'

const history = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Row>
        {transactions.map(tr => (
          <Fragment key={/* set a unique key here */}>
            <h3>{tr.type === "Rsend" ? "a" : "b"}</h3>
            <h3>aaa</h3>
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
};


export default history
```